# Move the background image of the div element with purely CSS

Tags: css, jquery-animate, background-image, keyframe

I'm trying to move the background image of the div element with purely CSS. Here i'm taking input the background-image url from user, thats why I can't declare it in CSS. I also cannot declare it as an image with position fixed or absolute as it would affect my rest of the CSS. Is there any way to write CSS only for the background of the div element?

Fiddle- [jsfiddle.net/ZTsG9](http://jsfiddle.net/ZTsG9/)

HTML:

```
<div class="view" style="background-image: url('http://css3slideshow.remabledesigns.com/1.jpg')">According to a new report from AnandTech, Samsung might be fibbing its way to more favorable Galaxy S4 benchmarks. Has your device suddenly come to a crawl? Of course it hasn’t; benchmarks shouldn’t change your perception of a flagship as powerful as the S4. Still, it’s embarrassing that Samsung would resort to such technical tactics, like allegedly using code dubbed “BenchmarkBooster.” Yes, your device takes steroids.</div>
```

CSS:

```
.view {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    animation:mymove 5s infinite;
    -webkit-animation:mymove 5s infinite;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
}
@keyframes mymove {
     from {
         left:0px;
     }
     to {
         left:200px;
     }
}
@-webkit-keyframes mymove
/* Safari and Chrome */
    {
     from {
          leftp:0px;
     }
     to {
         left:200px;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following trick seems to work: make the background image twice as wide as the element and change the horizontal part of the background-position from 0 to `-200%` ([edited **FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZTsG9/1/)):

```
.view {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    animation:mymove 5s linear infinite;
    background-size: 200% 100%; /* horizontal scale is 200% */
}
@keyframes mymove {
    from {
        background-position: 0% 0px;
    }
    to {
        background-position: -200% 0px; /* shifting the image to right by its full width */
    }
}
```

The arithmetic that moves the image when `background-position` is the negative percentage is well explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12737470/2533215).

Comment: Thanks. It worked great. Is there any way round, without stretching the image to 200% and loop the animation?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is add background-position: x, y where x and y equals the length and height of where you want to position your element. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

```
<div class="view" style="background-image: url('http://css3slideshow.remabledesigns.com/1.jpg') background-position:50px 20px;">
 According to a new report from AnandTech, Samsung might be fibbing its way to more favorable Galaxy S4 benchmarks. Has your device suddenly come to a crawl? Of course it hasn’t; benchmarks shouldn’t change your perception of a flagship as powerful as the S4. Still, it’s embarrassing that Samsung would resort to such technical tactics, like allegedly using code dubbed “BenchmarkBooster.” Yes, your device takes steroids.</div>
```